# Vue2 + webpack + deploy2war - get url from external xml file

Tags: webpack, vue.js

I am using the vue-cli boilerplate (Vue2 + webpack) + vuex + axios with the webpack-deploy2war plugin for creating a war file from the build.

Currently I am manually changing the server URL in the code before running a build for a production server or a build for a development server.

How do I configure the system so the war file would get the server URL from an external environment XML?